# Assign workflow_dispatch inputs of previous runs to new github workflow inputs

Tags: json, events, input, github-actions, github-api

I'm dealing with a single workflow that takes `workflow_dispatch` inputs from the user and runs. After the workflow logs have passed their retention limits (30 days) I need to rerun the same workflow the second time however, the second run should get the same inputs that were used for the first run more than 30 days earlier.

I wish to dynamically set the `key-value` for `workflow_dispatch` **inputs** by reading the `key-value` from a file generated by a previous run.

```
name: Redirect Inputs to File

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input1:
        description: 'Input 1'
        required: true
        default: 'Default Value 1'
      input2:
        description: 'Input 2'
        required: true
        default: 'Default Value 2'
      previousrunid:
        description: 'Enter previous runid'
        required: true
        default: '4356678'

jobs:
  redirect-inputs:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run PowerShell script to dump inputs to file STACK
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          $Inputs = @"
          ${{ toJson(github.event.inputs) }}
          "@ | ConvertFrom-Json
          
          $InputData = $Inputs | ConvertTo-Json
          Write-Host $InputData
          $InputData | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\inputs.json"
          Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\inputs.json"
```

If the user provides the previous `previousrunid` my workflow reads the inputs from `C:\Temp\inputs.json` and must assign the key-values to the current run inputs i.e `${{ github.event.inputs.<key> }}` if that is possible?

Reference: [How do we write GITHUB ACTIONS workflow_dispatch user inputs to a file and read it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78124522/how-do-we-write-github-actions-workflow-dispatch-user-inputs-to-a-file-and-read)

Comment: Did you evaluate calling the [Github API directly to send a dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) directly from the first workflow? You can send dynamic inputs that way, and this should work with `${{ toJson(github.event.inputs) }}` in the second workflow.

Comment: @GuiFalourd my first workflow should not trigger the second. i run the second workflow after the first workflow logs have passed their retention limits (30 days). My second run should get the same inputs that were used for the first run more than 30 days earlier.

Comment: @GuiFalourd i updated my original post explaining this requirement in detail.

Comment: I don't know if it will be possible to retrieve the inputs from the previous run. An option could be to save the github event context that trigger the previous run as artifact and keep it for 30 days, but I don't really know if this would work and how you would be able to update and retrieve this artifact automatically.